# specify alternate JAXB provider

Tags: java, grails, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

In my Grails app, I want to use [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the JAXB provider. I tried adding a file `grails-app\conf\jaxb.properties` with the contents

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

But it seems the default JAXB provider is still being used. I've confirmed that the relevant JARs for EclipseLink are on my runtime classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The `jaxb.properties` file needs to be added in the same package as your domain classes:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html